# SQLDependency hangs on SQL Server restart

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqldependency

I have application which registers multiple SQLDependencies; and events are fired when change occur in DB.

Everything works fine in normal circumstance but if we restart SQL Server multiple times then the new request to register notification gets hangs.

Took the dump and from analysis found out that a SQL thread with Undermentioned Stack. Does anyone have any idea what this thread is doing?

```cs
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean)
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, System.Data.SqlClient.BulkCopySimpleResultSet, System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(System.Data.SqlClient.ServerInfo, System.String, Boolean, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, System.Data.ProviderBase.TimeoutTimer)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.TimeoutTimer, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, System.String, Boolean)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, System.Object, System.String, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, Boolean)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroup)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher+SqlConnectionContainer.Restart(System.Object)
SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher+SqlConnectionContainer.AsyncResultCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean)
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteReader(System.IAsyncResult, System.String)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteReader(System.IAsyncResult)
SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher+SqlConnectionContainer.AsyncResultCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
System.Data.Common.DbAsyncResult.ExecuteCallback(System.Object)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Comment: What was the exception message?

Comment: Never get the exception message it just hangs there. I took this stack from dump

Comment: This other question may be related: [Hang in System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33225828/1364007).

Comment: When I had this problem I fixed it by deleting the instance: `SqlLocalDB delete v11.0`.